# How to insert an ELSE IF in as google sheets, as I can't seem to use 2 IF Statements in the same cell?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formula

I am trying to make a formula that changes depending on the cell containing the sex value however I can't seem to correct it. I am new to spreadsheets so I may be missing a big and obvious step.

=IF(C3="Female" (655.1+(9.563*C6)+(1.850*C7)-(4.676*C4)) ELSE IF (C3="Male" (66.5+(13.75*C6)+(5.003*C7)-(6.75*C4))))

Comment: Need a comma after the logical test and in the value_if_false no need for else.

Answer (score 0):

So, without an example, this is how I would edit / correct your existing formula:

```
=IF(C3="Female",(655.1+(9.563 * C6)+(1.850 * C7)-(4.676 * C4)),IF(C3="Male",(66.5+(13.75 * C6)+(5.003 * C7)-(6.75 * C4),"error")))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(C3="Female"; 
 (655.1+(9.563*C6)+(1.850*C7)-(4.676*C4)); 
 (66.5+(13.75*C6)+(5.003*C7)-(6.75*C4))))
```